# how to use regexp to select files in a specific order? - matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

Let's say I have 14 files with names:

```
file_001.txt file_002.txt file_003.txt file_004.txt ... file_014.txt
```

I'm trying to write a regex that selects my files in a specific order. Assuming `ls` outputs:

```
file_001.txt  file_002.txt  file_003.txt ... file_014.txt
```

`regexp(ls ,'file_0+([135]|[246])\.txt','match')` gives me:

```
file_001.txt  
file_002.txt  
file_003.txt
file_004.txt
file_005.txt
file_006.txt
```

but what I'm aiming at is:

```
file_001.txt  
file_003.txt
file_005.txt
file_002.txt  
file_004.txt
file_006.txt
```

Comment: What is the formula algorithm to help us understand the sequence `1/3/5/2/5/6` ?

Comment: @zx81: The 1/3/5/2/4/6 was just an example, it could as well be 1/2/5/6/3/4. I'd just like to know if it's possible to order the files in a specific user-defined way.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is simply not the right tool for this.

You'll end up with an expression that looks like this:

```
file_([1-9][0-9]?|100)[1-5][5-8](12[1-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-2][0-9])(73[89]|7[4-9][0-9]|8[0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[01])(9|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|[1-7][0-9]{3}|80[0-9]{2}|81[01][0-9]|812[0-8])(83[4-9]|8[4-9][0-9]|9[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])\.txt
```